# Change div id on click of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now I'm working to create a website that can showcase multiple images on the homepage, that can cycle by the click of a button. Almost like a gallery but more geared towards page previews. What I am trying to figure out is how to change a div's id/class when a button is clicked.

I have looked at a few other questions, but none that show this happening for 4 different ids.

I am very new to JavaScript, and am trying to figure it out to best suit my situation.

Here is the jsFiddle that I have made for my page. The goal is to have the buttons at the top change the green div `#Filler` to a new id/class on click.

http://jsfiddle.net/xCGDT/1/

```
#Filler {
margin: auto;
max-height: 700px;
width: 1400px;
background-color: green;
max-width: 1366px;
height: 800px;
z-index: 1;
margin-top: -250px;
overflow: inherit;
background-image: url(nature5.jpg);
animation: Filler 1s 1;
-webkit-animation: Filler 1s 1;
transition-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
opacity:1; }
```

changed to

```
#Filler2 {
margin: auto;
max-height: 700px;
width: 1400px;
background-color: red;
max-width: 1366px;
height: 800px;
z-index: 1;
margin-top: -250px;
overflow: inherit;
animation: Filler 1s 1;
-webkit-animation: Filler 1s 1;
transition-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
opacity:1;

}
```

Like I said I'm very new to this, and this is for a WebDesign class project.

Comment: You can't do that with HTML and CSS alone. You need JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I realize that I can't use css*for this, which is why I'm asking here as to how it would be done with javascript

Answer (score 6):

Use Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('Filler').id = 'Filler2';
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

Include jquery library and do as

```
$(function() {
    $('#Filler').click(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', 'Filler2');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added jquery to my fiddle but I'm not sure as to how this code helps me out.

Comment: Ok nevermind I get it now. I was hoping to have the buttons at the top change the id, not clicking the div itself :P

Answer (score 3):

The following will change the class or id of a given element (answering your question)

```
var element = document.getElementById("myElement");
element.setAttribute("class", "aNewClass");
element.setAttribute("id", "aNewID");
```

but I wouldn't approach things in the way your fiddle is suggesting you are

I'd define shared CSS with a # element selector and then the differences in . class selectors and swap out the classes only

here's an example
http://jsfiddle.net/thisishardcoded/XRgbM/

Comment: Oh I guess I had . and # backwards then. Thanks for the example.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It took me a while but I understand how this code works, and made this: http://jsfiddle.net/XRgbM/2/

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: node.setAttribute.

An important advice:
Do not use repeated IDs in your HTML. IDs are supposed to identify a single node. Instead use classes if you require several items with the same identifier.

You can put this code in your fiddle and it works as requested.

```
var links = document.getElementById('Nav').getElementsByTagName('A');
var filler = document.getElementById('Filler');
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++) (function(j){
    links[j].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        filler.setAttribute('id', 'Filler'+(j?j:''));
    });
})(i);
```

Also see the jQuery examples in other answers your life would be a lot easier.

Comment: Indeed it does! Thanks! One thing I notice with this though is when I switch between the two ids it does not play the animation again, which is what I was hoping to be able to do

Comment: The problem is that your css animations are designed to change the opacity from current to 100%, so the only way to trigger the animations is by clicking LINK2 which takes the opacity back to 0 and then going to any other button. If you want to animate the background you have to add this to your CSS (you can use more specific selector if you want).
`div {
    transition: background 2s;
    -webkit-transition: background 2s; /* Safari */
}`